# Adapter is not working as expected in my test device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

i have started to develop and implement adapter successfully in ibm web console and also android mobile browser simulator. But when installed in my real test device the adapter is not able to connect to the database. i do no where to find error log in mobile.

```
currentPage={};

currentPage.init = function() {
    WL.Logger.debug("Page2 :: init");
};


currentPage.back = function(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Page2 :: back");
    $("#pagePort").load(pagesHistory.pop());
};
function loadSQLRecords(){
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'dball',
        procedure : 'getDball',
        parameters : []
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : loadSQLQuerySuccess,
        onFailure : loadSQLQueryFailure
    });
}

function loadSQLQuerySuccess(result){        
   alert ("success");
    if (result.invocationResult.resultSet.length > 0) 
        displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
    else 
        alert("failure here");



    }

function loadSQLQueryFailure() {
    alert ("failure");
}

function displayFeeds(result){      
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $("#mytable").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].EMPID + "</td></tr>");
        $("#mytable").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].EMPNAME + "</td></tr>");   
        $("#mytable").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].EMAILID + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <!--     Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.

  --> 
- <wl:adapter name="dball" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration" xmlns:sql="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/sql">
  <displayName>dball</displayName> 
  <description>dball</description> 
- <connectivity>
- <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
- <!--  Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name 
  --> 
- <!--  <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> 
  --> 
- <!--  Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder 
  --> 
- <dataSourceDefinition>
  <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass> 
  <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.*.***:****:****</url> 
  <user>****</user> 
  <password>****</password> 
  </dataSourceDefinition>
  </connectionPolicy>
  </connectivity>
- <!--  Replace this with appropriate procedures 
  --> 
  <procedure name="getDball" /> 
  <procedure name="addDball" /> 
  </wl:adapter>
```

Comment: 1) Add the adapter XML to the question 2) Is the device connected to the same network as the host machine where the server is?

Comment: i am using the ecliplse plugin mobile frirst studio so the server is integrated in my same machine .i can access the server url through my test device browser.

Comment: Answer my 2 questions. The device must be connected to the same network as the host in order for the adapter to work when testing in a device.

Comment: yes both are in same network

Comment: Use your public IP address instead of 192.168...

Comment: are you mentioning the above 192.168. oracle database server url .it is external ip address and is open to public

Comment: What is the response from the adapter invocation's onFailure? NOT your "alert()" code, but the response object. Add your client-side code.

Comment: where do i find response object in my mobile are you mentioning some error log where i can find. also i have implemented multipage application so there is lot of client side code which one to insert.

Comment: Add the code that calls the adapter procedure and its onSuccess and onFailure callbacks.

Comment: i am getting failure msg from loadsqlquery function()

Comment: Change it to the following in order to see the real error: `function loadSQLQueeryFailure(response) {alert("******* Error is: " + response.errorMsg);}`

Comment: i get "Error is UNDEFINED" from my mobile

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but you are clearly doing it wrong and there is not enough code provided to debug it. Upload your project somewhere so it could be downloaded and debugged.

Comment: it works in console and also in mobile browse simulator perfectly

Comment: Provide your project.

Comment: can i provide my project without adapter.xml because it contains my company database server details

Comment: Replace it  with dummy info.

Comment: @IdanAdar   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_un-SB-HiYqaTZTd2NPclkwLVU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I took your project and changed the database settings to connect to mine instead (MySQL). The connection was successful and data was saved in the database.

Even if forcing it to fail, it does not fail with "Error is UNDEFINED", so I still believe this does have to do with your Oracle database settings. 192.168 is internal IP address - it is not available as a public IP address even if you think it is. It does not. You need to check this with your IT department and get the real IP address of your database.

Comment: ok can u just say me why we need to change it  as available to public because i try to connect to adapter only not directly the backend service ??

Comment: 192.168 is NOT a public IP address. It is a local IP address. It is not the correct address to use. Did you actually talk with your company's IT administrator?

Comment: yep he says its a external ip address only.

Comment: If I will attempt to connect to your "external IP address", it will fail because it is not a PUBLIC IP address.

Comment: did you try i have not provided ip itself..anyway did anyone face this issue it runs on my console also mobile browser simulator but not in test device .i have a demo tmrw

Comment: The preview and MBS are LOCAL to the server. You are previewing data right in the server. Locally. Unlike a device that needs to connect to the server.

Comment: sir, just for clarification my client code connects to adapter which connects to oracle database and adapter is deployed in server my host computer and the oracle database to adapter is functioning fine  then why the issue arises pls excuse me if i am wrong